# How to Vary the width of Interactive Report Column in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, interactive, oracle-apex-5

I have one simple Interactive report build in `Apex 5.0`. Its just simple plain statement pulling the data from table.

I need to adjust the size of each column in the so that data properly appears in the report.

Right now what is happening is that i have column called customer which contains customer name. Now name is `30` to `40` characters long and in the report it is getting broken down in two lines.

I tried using the following but there is no effect of this. Could you please help me to fix this. I have `30` columns in the report.

`#apexir_NAME{width: 200px;}`

Answer (score 6):

You should try this using **Column Formatting** and set **HTML Expression** value like this

```
<div style="display:block; width:200px">#COLUMN_NAME_OF_REPORT#</div>
```

for example:

```
<div style="display:block; width:200px">#DEPT_ID#</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To change interactive column width:

1. Add static id to interactive report eg.  **myReport**
2. Add static id for column in report eg. **myColumn1**
3. Add to inline css of page below code:

myReport td[headers=myColumn1]{ width:100px; }

Note:  **before myReport td put #**

Answer (score 1):

Use `min-width` instead. You could use either of the following:

```
#apexir_NAME {min-width:200px;}
```

or

```
th#NAME {min-width:200px;}
```

To set all of them at once, you could try something like this:

```
table.apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA th {min-width:200px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do i need to set this at page level or region level?

Comment: If you are on Apex 5.0 and you have more than one IR on the page I'd say you'd have to change the css selector - defining it in the region won't make a difference.

Comment: I tried all the of the option but it didn't work. I tried putting in the pages header also region header but there is no impact.

Comment: Probably means you haven't picked the right css selector for your theme. I find using Chrome or Firefox's element inspector the best way to diagnose this sort of issue. Alternatively, put a sample of your app on https://apex.oracle.com and we can have a look.